# Complex conjugation map is not properly homotopic to the identity map of complex plane

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology, de-rham-cohomology

**Definition:** A map $f:X\to Y$ between two topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ is said to be *proper* if $f^{-1}(K)\subseteq_\text{compact} X$ for every $K\subseteq_\text{compact} Y$. A homotopy $H:X\times [0,1]\to Y$ is said to be *proper homotopy* if $H$ is a proper map.

> **Problem:** Consider the plane $\Bbb R^2$ and two maps $\text{Id},\overline{\text{Id}}:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^2$ defined as
> follows $\text{Id}(x,y)=(x,y)$ and $\overline{\text{Id}}(x,y)=(x,-y)$
> for all $(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2$. Does there exist a *proper homotopy*
> $H:\Bbb R^2\times [0,1]\to \Bbb R^2$ such that $H(-,0)=\text{Id}$ and
> $H(-,1)=\overline{\text{Id}}$?

Note that any two maps of $\Bbb R^2=\Bbb C$ are homotopic via a convex combination. For example $G:\Bbb R^2\times [0,1]\to \Bbb R^2$ defined by $G\big((x,y),t\big)=\big(x,(1-2t)y\big)$ is a homotopy between $\text{Id}$ and $\overline{\text{Id}}$, but $G$ is not a *proper homotopy*.

Note also that, $\overline{\text{Id}}\circ \overline{\text{Id}}=\text{Id}$. Now, if we use [compactly-supported cohomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohomology_with_compact_support) then $H^2_\text{c}(\Bbb R^2;\Bbb Z)=\Bbb Z$ and we can talk about degree of a proper map: $\deg_\text{c}(\text{Id})=1$ and $\deg_\text{c}(\overline{\text{Id}})\cdot\deg_\text{c}(\overline{\text{Id}})=1$ i.e. $\deg_\text{c}(\overline{\text{Id}})=\pm 1$. Note that $\deg_\text{c}$ is invariant under *proper homotopy*. My guess is that $\deg_\text{c}(\overline{\text{Id}})=-1$, but I have no proof. **Is there any other approach?**

Thank you.

Comment: Consider closed 2-disk $D^2$ and a reflection $r: D^2\to D^2$. Do you know how to compute the induced map $r^*: H^2(D^2,\partial D^2)\to H^2(D^2,\partial D^2)$?

Comment: Sorry, reflection or antipodal map, for the former $H_2(D^2,\partial D^2)\to H_2(D^2,\partial D^2)$ is multiplication by $-1$ and the latter $(-1)^{1+1}=1$. At first, one has to consider at homology level and use the degree, then using Universal-Coefficients theorem for cohomology, the evaluation homomorphism is an isomorphism as $\text{Ext}$ vanishes. Hence, we have the same results i.e. either multiplication by $-1$ or by $+1$ respectively.

Comment: Right. Now, exhaust the complex plane by concentric disks and use the above computation to determine the map of $H^2_c$.

Comment: Okay, then direct limit answer $-1$. Is there any other way, like using **end**

Comment: You can also use the excision. Yes, you can use the end-cohomology, but it amounts to the same computation. All these arguments are essentially the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have a proper homotopy $f_t:\mathbb C\times I\rightarrow \mathbb C$ with $f_0(z)=z$ and $f_1(z)=\bar z$.

We can extend this to a homotopy of the Riemann sphere $\mathbb C\mathbb P^1$ by defining $f_t(\infty)=\infty$ for all $t\in I$. Then continuity of $f_t:\mathbb C\mathbb P^1\times I\rightarrow \mathbb C\mathbb P^1$ follows from the properness of our original homotopy. But now $f_0$ is the identity and $f_1$ is a reflection of the Riemann sphere, so they have degrees $1$ and $-1$, respectively. This is a contradiction because degree is a homotopy invariant.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, we have already proved it in the comment section(why the degree of reflection is $-1$). Thanks for your interest. If you have any alternative proof of why the degree is $-1$, you can write.